# Can't link custom shared library with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to write my own shared library to link to an executable, but can't get the `.so` to link.

I'm using a very basic example to try and get it working. The shared library (`test_lib.c`):

```
#include "test_lib.h" //stdlib includes and function prototype

char *hello(void)   {
    char *c = malloc(100);
    memcpy(c, "hello\n", 7);
    return c;
}
```

The executable (`test.c`):

```
#include "test_lib.h"

int main()  {
    printf("%s", hello());
    return 0;
}
```

Following all the guides I can find, I compile the `.so` with `gcc -I . -fPIC -shared -o test_lib.so test_lib.c`, and then the executable (in the same directory) with `gcc -I . -L . test.c -ltest_lib`

This gives the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest_lib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I understand including the path through the `-L` flag should tell gcc where to find the `.so`, but this isn't working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to compile the so to `-o libtest.so` and then link with `-ltest`. Or alternativly pass the full name to `-ltest_lib.so` and you might pass `-L.`as well.

Comment: Changing the name to `libtest.so` works, thanks. For the record `-ltest_lib.so` didn't though.

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure aboiut the full name. I think you have to pass the path as well in that case. Anyway, renaming it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking a library, the library usually has to be named `libxxx.a|so` for the linker to find it.

Compiling the library:

```
gcc -I . -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so test_lib.c
```

Then you can link with:

```
gcc -I . -L . test.c -ltest
```